# call method on returned value of another method in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to call method on returned value from another method of same class.

```
class A():

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def values(self,key):
        return list(list(x.values())[0] for x in self.data['data'] if key in x.keys())

    def length(self):
        return len(self)

data ={"data":[{"country":"india"},{"state":"punjab"},{"country":"usa"}]}
obj = A(data)
res = obj.values('country') # returns ['india', 'usa']
res1 = obj.values('country').length() #  returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'length'
print(res)
print(res1)
```

i want both res and res1 to work.

I have also tried using @property decorator

```
class B():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def __call__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        return self

    @property
    def values(self):
        self.valu =  list(list(x.values())[0] for x in self.data['data'] if self.key in x.keys())
        return self

    def length(self):
        return len(self.valu)

data ={"data":[{"country":"india"},{"state":"punjab"},{"country":"usa"}]}
obj = B(data)
res = obj('country').values.length()     #  returns 2
res1 = obj('country').values      # returns <__main__.A object at 0x103a9fbe0>
print(res)
print(res1)
```

This way res works but res1 does not.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to invoke `B.length` on the return value of `values`, then it has to return an instance of `B`. You can't expect a list to know about `B` methods.

Comment: add res1 = obj('country').values.valu this should work.  obj('country').values return the self object and you can access any property you set on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the confusion here is on what object is the `.length` method invoked. In the first case, it is invoked on a `list` which does not have a `.length` method. In the second case, it is invoked on the `B` object which indeed has a `.length` method. The most straightforward and preferred solution is what @Subhrajyoti Das suggested.

If you still want your code (as described in the question) to work (or just want to know if this could actually be done), you could define a custom list object which would look like as follows:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def length(self):
        return len(self)
```

Now instead of making a `list`, you would make a `CustomList`.

Edit: Adding the complete example, as requested in the comment.

```
class CustomList(list):
    def length(self):
        return len(self)

class A():

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def values(self,key):
        return CustomList(CustomList(x.values())[0] for x in self.data['data'] if key in x.keys())

    def length(self):
        return len(self)

data ={"data":[{"country":"india"},{"state":"punjab"},{"country":"usa"}]}
obj = A(data)
res = obj.values('country') # returns ['india', 'usa']
res1 = obj.values('country').length() # 2
object has no attribute 'length'
print(res)
print(res1)
```

Comment: Thanks . Can you tell me how exactly i can use this class?

Comment: @RustamSinghGarg I have updated the answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

`.length()` is not a python list function. Use `len(listobject)` instead.

Eg:

```py
len(obj('country').values)
```

If you want to print the values. In your second example:

```py
#Use 
res1 = obj('country').data

#instead of
res1 = obj('country').values
```

Use below code to get list of countries

```py
res1 = [_dict.get('country') for _dict in obj('country').data.get('data') if 'country' in _dict.keys()]

print(res1)
#['india', 'usa']
```

Final Updated working code:

```py
class B():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def __call__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        return self

    @property
    def values(self):
        self.valu =  list(list(x.values())[0] for x in self.data['data'] if self.key in x.keys())
        return self

    def length(self):
        return len(self.valu)

data ={"data":[{"country":"india"},{"state":"punjab"},{"country":"usa"}]}
obj = B(data)
res = obj('country').values.length()     #  returns 2
res1 = [_dict.get('country') for _dict in obj('country').data.get('data') if 'country' in _dict.keys()]      # returns ['usa', 'india']
print(res)
print(res1)
```

Comment: i know .what i am doing is making list of custom methods and will call these methods on objects

Comment: @RustamSinghGarg `obj.values('country')` returns a list and you do not have a `.length()` for list.

Comment: obj('country').data returns whole data. what i want is ['india', 'usa']

Comment: Getting error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'length'